# computed slice position is different from the one in DICOM file

Tags: dicom

I am implementing a method to spatially sort DICOM slices in a volume. The way I am doing it is to sort by the position along the slice normal. This is computed as:

```
slice_normal = [0, 0, 0] 
dir_cosines = ds[0x0020, 0x0037]  # Direction cosines 
slice_normal[0] = dir_cosines[1] * dir_cosines[5] - dir_cosines[2] * dir_cosines[4] 
slice_normal[1] = dir_cosines[2] * dir_cosines[3] - dir_cosines[0] * dir_cosines[5] 
slice_normal[2] = dir_cosines[0] * dir_cosines[4] - dir_cosines[1] * dir_cosines[3] 

image_pos = ds[0x0020, 0x0032]  # IPP 
distance_along_normal = 0 
for i in range(len(slice_normal)): 
    distance_along_normal += slice_normal[i] * image_pos[i]
```

Now this value `distance_along_normal` should be equal to the `slice location(0x0020, 0x1041)`, except in my case it has the opposite sign. So the slice ordering seems to be reversed than what it should be. I would like to know ehat else must I need to take something else into account to compute the correct slice ordering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no reason to expect that the sign or the value of the offset calculated by your implementation should be the same as the sign or the value of the `Slice Location (0020,1041)` value. As per DICOM specification

> Slice Location (0020,1041) is defined as the relative position of the
>   image plane expressed in mm. This information is relative to an
>   unspecified implementation specific reference point.

Note that the direction of location is not specified at all, and it is explicitly said that the origin is arbitrary, which means that the only thing guaranteed to match between your calculation and the `Slice Location` is the distance (absolute value of the difference) of the positions of any 2 slices.

Also note that `Slice Location` is Type 3 - it does not have to be provided at all.

With regards to slice ordering - the presentation order is your decision. If you want spatial ordering, you need to decide the criteria for your ordering. For example, should axial slices be presented beginning from the head, or from the feet? That is your call completely and it will depend on the application (intended use) of your software.

If you do NOT care for the geometry, you can present images ordered for example by `Instance Number (0020,0013)`. But there is no guarantee the ordering will have any geometrical meaning (although it usually has).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That reassures me a bit. However, how would the anatomical labels make sense if this ordering is arbitrary?

Comment: Which anatomical labels do you have in mind - `Patient Orientation (0020,0020)`? If so, note that this is only in-plane orientation. The slice ordering does not influence in-plane orientation. Also, by the way, the value of `Patient Orientation` has to be consistent with the value of `Image Orientation (Patient)`, if both values are present.

Comment: I meant when scrolling in the through place direction...how can one determine whether one is going from head->toe or the other way around if he ordering is not unique.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood the question, that has no connection to the underlying DICOM data, has it?

Comment: Well, I am thinking that if I have a 3D volume and I want to be able to label the anatomical directions properly (in all three orthogonal planes) that the ordering of the slices would matter, right? I mean, if I have them ordered with slice position increasing or decreasing would flip the label in the through-plane direction.

Comment: The third (normal) axis orientation for your specific image is only given by it's orientation vectors (row and column cosines). I.e., if your image has patient's anterior on the upper side and patient's left on right-hand side, then you are looking in the direction from feet to head. Head is 'behind' this image; feet are 'in front' (figuratively; of course if the image is mid-head, head is on both sides).

Comment: Ah right...I see what you mean now...DICOM is confusing. Thanks again!